# Python influxdb timestamp valueerror

Tags: python, database, timestamp, influxdb, valueerror

I am trying to use write_points() to add data to an influxdb database in python. However, I am getting an error with the timestamp portion of write_points. I have tried to define the timestamp multiple ways, first using

```
info = line.split()
s_time = info[2]
i_time = "20" + s_time[6:8] + "-" + s_time[0:2] + "-" + s_time[3:5] + ' ' + s_time[9:]
fixedtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(i_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and adding the time to the JSON with all the other parts required for influxdb
I also tried making the time stamp an int

```
inttime = int(time.time()*1000);
```

which gives me the epoch time. 
Both of these time stamps raises a value error from this line in my code

```
dbclient.write_points(db_point, time_precision='ms', protocol='json')
```

and at the final line of

```
    if isinstance(timestamp, Integral):
        return timestamp  # assume precision is correct if timestamp is int
    if isinstance(_get_unicode(timestamp), text_type):
        timestamp = parse(timestamp)
    if isinstance(timestamp, datetime):
        if not timestamp.tzinfo:
            timestamp = UTC.localize(timestamp)
        ns = (timestamp - EPOCH).total_seconds() * 1e9
        if precision is None or precision == 'n':
            return ns
        elif precision == 'u':
            return ns / 1e3
        elif precision == 'ms':
            return ns / 1e6
        elif precision == 's':
            return ns / 1e9
        elif precision == 'm':
            return ns / 1e9 / 60
        elif precision == 'h':
            return ns / 1e9 / 3600
    raise ValueError(timestamp)
```

in line_protocol.py

When I use the epoch time the integer somehow gets converted to a set so it doesn't pass any of the if statements, but I don't know why the string does pass one of the if statements

Answer (score 2):

The [FAQ says](https://support.influxdb.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177928-What-time-formats-are-allowed-) RFC3339 and RFC3339Nano are supported for the JSON protocol. Its format ([as implemented in the Go](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)) is like "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" (note the "T"), or just use [datetime.datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).